# What is the song from Naruto Shippuden episode 48 - Bonds at 3:10?

Tags: naruto, music

This song is common in many episodes and even appears several times in one episode. It's kind of a sad music with male vocals and instrumentals such as some kind of flute or something similar. It's from episode 48 titled "Bonds" of Naruto Shippuden and starts close to 3:10.

Comment: You may want to check it out on amazon.co.jp or youtube.com for the OST CDs

Answer (score 7):

it's this song here

[Naruto Shippuden OST 1 - Track 28 - Shippuu Kumikyoku ( Hurricane Suite )](https://youtu.be/P5Hp42y7gVA)

the singing starts at 0:40

Comment: well, than mark my answer as correct answer, please :)
So everyone can see that this is answered :)